# Expose fields with underscore with FOS REST Bundle

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

I have a setup where I use Symfony 3.2, Doctrine and a Form for validation. I want to expose the entities via REST using the FOS REST Bundle. However, I need to expose the fields how the appear in the schema (underscored) and not in the entity (CamelCase).

For the PUT/POST/PATCH actions I discovered that I can modify the fields in the FormType as follows:

```
class CountryType extends AbstractType

     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

            $builder->add('iso_alpha2', null, array('property_path' => 'isoAlpha2')
            ...
     }
}
```

This works well, but as I said, this only works for write actions.

The thing I struggle with is that I cannot get the GET actions return the schema fields (underscored) - how do I do this?

Comment: doesn't `serialized_name` fit your needs? you can use it while serializing your entity fields. there is also `property_naming`, maybe it can be useful! http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference

Comment: As I'm using annotations I did try to import the JMS ones and added `@JMS\SerializedName("iso_alpha2")` to my Entity's field. Unfortunately this had no effect. Do I need to configure something else for JMS to pick it up? I found the documentation to be rather confusing.

Comment: did you tried @Serializer/SerializedName? please to read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738466/symfony2-jmsserializerbundle-changes-the-attribute-name-from-classname-to-cl

Comment: Yes, but I imported as JMS, that's why it's @JMS\SerializedName. I also tried to set `serialized_name_annotation_strategy` without success. I verified that JMS is properly working in this file by adding @JMS\Exclude for testing. This worked, so unsure why `SerializedName` doesn't. In fact - underscored outputs apparently are the default by JMS - as also mentioned in the link you sent me. For now I changed my the output format to CamelCase as I can't fix the issue - Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help till you find a complete solution, but as you said, stick to camelCase to do not waste more time with it, until maybe, someone from SO come up with an idea. nice day